# Postgraphile: multiple foreignkeys on same table with smart tags and postgraphile.tags.json5

Tags: postgraphile

NodeJS Project with apollo/postgraphile

I would like to add multiple virtual foreignkey on multiple tables with postgraphile Smart Tags using postgraphile.tags.json5

If i do this in postgraphile.tags.json5

```
tags: {
  foreignKey: "(col1_id) REFERENCES table1 (id)",
  foreignKey: "(col2_id) REFERENCES table2 (id)"
}
```

Then only latest foreignKey tag will work.

How can i manage to add multiple foreignKey tag referencings columns from differents table ?

Comment: Finally found it by using array. tags: { foreignKey: ["(col1_id) REFERENCES table1 (id)", "(col2_id) REFERENCES table2 (id)" ] }